# C# WPF Webbrowser save Selection and highlight Text

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, browser

I want to select some Text or some Elements, with the mouse, in a wpf webbrowser and save the selection, so that I can send it to an other PC/wpf webbrowser and highlight it with a red font or background like "...".

I found the IHTMLTxtRange but is it possible to set it programmatically?

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: when you mean webbrowser, do you wish to present html webpages or you just want to render texts and images with formatted form?

Comment: i mean a real html web Page like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page.

Comment: for example: I load the wikipedia Site in a WPF Webbrowser and mark the Article of the Day.By Button press, I want do get some Values (StartPos, EndPos?) that represents the Selection,so that i can take  it to an other WPF Webbrowser to mark the selected text with red.